# Convert Javascript Ternary Function to simple function

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-operator

I have a ternary function

```
const resetCompletion = completed < 0 ? 0 : completed > 100 ? 100 : completed;
```

I need to convert it into a simple function of `if else if else` block. What should be the proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code snippet could be an equivalent to your ternary operations by if block.

```js
const resetCompletion = completed => {
  if (completed < 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (completed > 100) {
    return 100;
  }
  return completed;
};

let completed = 101;
console.log(resetCompletion(completed));

completed = -100;
console.log(resetCompletion(completed));

completed = 10;
console.log(resetCompletion(completed));
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be expanded to something like that:

```
let resetCompletion = completed;

if (completed < 0) { resetCompletion = 0; }
else if (completed > 100) { resetCompletion = 100; }
```

Which means *"By default, `resetCompletion` is equal to `completion`. However, if `completed` is less than zero, then `resetCompletion` is equal to zero, else if `completed` is greater than 100, then `resetCompletion` is equal to 100"*